# Bound on inconsistent set for the guarded fragment

Tags: first-order-logic

**Context**: suppose $\phi$ is a formula in the Guarded Fragment of First Order Logic, $\phi$ is
without constants and without function symbols.
Let $I$ be a finite set, $(R_i)_{i \in I}$ relation symbols and $C$ a finite set of constants.
Let $A = \{R_i(a_1,...a_{n_i}) \ | \ i \in I, a_j \in C\}$,
that is, $A$ is is a finite set of assertions (suppose arities of relation symbols are of course
respected).
The expression $\phi \wedge \bigwedge_{\varphi \in A}\varphi$ is inconsistent if no model of
it exists.

**The question is**: let $\phi$ be such a formula, can we compute a bound $M$ such that if $A$
is a finite set of assertions and $\phi \wedge \bigwedge_{\varphi \in A}\varphi$ is inconsistent
then there exists $A' \subseteq A$ with $|A'| \le M$ and
$\phi \wedge \bigwedge_{\varphi \in A'}\varphi$ inconsistent.